# Windows 8 store image inside local storage

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Now when I save the image it will prompt out FileSavePicker. Can I programmatically save the image in local storage instead call the FileSavePicker. Please help Thanks.

```
   FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG image", new List<string>() { ".png" });

    if (sourceFile == null)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage));
    }

    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "CroppedImage";
    StorageFile cropfile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    cropAndSaveImage(cropfile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I would recommend reading the entire page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx), because it covers most of the common variations you'll want to consider. In particular you will probably be interested in the `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` and the [application data sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx).

The solution will still involve getting a `StorageFile` at some point, of course, so it wouldn't be difficult to fit into the code you provided. Instead of opening a picker, you use `CreateFileAsync` method on a `StorageFolder` you get by using `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` (or one of the variations).